# Can standard iOS UIBarButtonSystemItem icons be referenced through storyboard Attributes Inspector?

Tags: ios, xcode6, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

The app that I am writing uses a navigation bar and I need to put a standard 'Add' (plus) icon as a bar button item. These standard icons are described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW33) and their use is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem), but the documentation only describes how to reference the icons from code (objective-c or swift).

None of the resources I can find on the subject covers how to specify the image source through the Attributes inspector, where I would set the icon source if it was based on a custom image. Is it not possible to reference default system icons through the Attributes inspector for the Bar Button Item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not intuitive, but the Xcode Attributes inspector has a setting for the Bar Button Item, called 'System Item' (or 'Identifier' in older Xcode versions). When selected it reveals a drop-down menu with identifiers for the system icons. Select the relevant identifier and the Bar Button Item icon will change to the matching icon.

Comment: Can't find it. Can you please share a pic or something.

Comment: Never mind. Found it. The title is currently displayed as 'System Item' and it is still not intuitive :)